# order by table with parent column in tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with parent column defined.

[image]

And I need to order this table with PARENT_A column like this

[image]

How can i do that with t-sql ?

Thanks.

Comment: 0,1,0,2 doesn't look like an ordered list.

Comment: Is there just one level of hierarchy or could there be a fifth row with `PARENT_A` equal to `3` that should sort between rows `3` and `2` in your expected output?

Comment: actually 2 level oh hierarch. First A column, and after PARENT_A column which PARENT_A equals A column.

Comment: first row A =1 , and after second row PARENT_A = 1,  A = 2, and after row PARENT_A = 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's just two levels, as your comment seems to indicate, then this is straightforward:

```
SELECT A,Parent_A
FROM UnnamedTable
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN Parent_A = 0 THEN A ELSE Parent_A END,  --Sort parents together with their children
  Parent_A --Ensure parents sort before their children
```

If there can actually be multiple levels then you need to use something like a recursive CTE:

```
declare @t table (
    A int not null,
    Parent_A int not null)
insert into @t (A,Parent_A) values
(1,0),(2,0),(3,1),(4,2),(5,3)

;With Hier as (
    select A,'/' + CONVERT(varchar(max),A) + '/' as position
    from @t where Parent_A = 0
    union all
    select t.A,position + CONVERT(varchar(max),t.A) + '/'
    from Hier h
        inner join
        @t t
            on
                h.A = t.Parent_A
), Converted as (
    select A,CONVERT(hierarchyid,position) as position
    from Hier
)
select t.A,t.Parent_A
from Converted c
      inner join
     @t t
      on c.A = t.A
order by c.position
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH TableA AS (
  SELECT 1 AS pk,0 AS REF
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,2
), CTE AS (
  SELECT pk AS masterid, pk AS basePK, REF AS baseRef
  FROM TableA
  WHERE REF = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT B.masterid, A.pk, A.REF
  FROM TableA AS A
  INNER JOIN CTE AS B ON B.basePK = A.REF
  WHERE A.REF <> 0
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
ORDER BY masterid,basepk
```